# Gravitational Force

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity, friction

If energy is represented by Acceleration=A, then

am=F  ams=W  (ams)/t=P

Acceleration is always present when motion is present, acceleration is the energy.

Since gravity translates into acceleration, and acceleration turns to Force with mass, and force turns to work with distance, and work to power with time, doesn't it stand to reason that acceleration never goes away and that therefore acceleration represents energy, therefore gravity is energy because acceleration is energy?

Gravity acts on all different masses in a peculiar fashion.  If you measure the amount of force it takes to accelerate a 100 lbs ball to 10 mph on an even surface and the amount of force needed to accelerate a 10 lbs ball to 10 mph on an even surface, the larger mass would require more force.

But gravity doesn't exert force in the way you and I do, it doesn't respond to mass at all except in one way, Gravity accelerates mass.  When gravity accelerates the 10 lbs ball at 32.2 ft/s^2 and when gravity accelerates the 100 lbs ball at 32.2 ft/s^2, two different forces are generated simultaneously.

I suggest this is because gravity behaves the way an electro-magnetic field behaves, where momentum is ignored during acceleration.

Gravity ignores mass when accelerating, so what is gravity?

Gravity appears to act equally on some part of all the molecules in an object, creating a density effect.  The energy of gravity gives mass its weight and that is why weight is measured like a force.  I am starting to think all energy comes from life in some way form or fashion, but mass gets weight from energy vectors.  Energy and force behave the same way accept that pure energy is expressed in acceleration where as force is expressed as a product of mass and energy.

Maybe gravity accelerates all molecules equally, thus generating unequal forces (varying energy) but constant acceleration.  Like the more molecules, the more points of access gravity has.

Guide on translating forces:

Acceleration to force: multiply the  acceleration by mass.  F=ma
Force to work: multiply the Force by distance. W=Fs (s=distance)
Work to power: divide by time. P=W/t

Power to Work: Pt=W
Work to Force:  F=W/s (s=distance)
Force to Acceleration: F/M=A

Power to force multiply the power by the time and divide by the distance.
Acceleration to Power: (AMs)/t=P (s=distance t=time)
Power to Acceleration: Pt/(Ms)=A (s=distance t=time)

P(t/s)=W/s =  F = MA = M (v^2/r)
[s=distance, t=time, P=power, W=work, F=force, M=mass, A=acceleration, V=velocity, r=radius]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*From another comment:*

> I wonder why the object with greater mass does not accelerate slower

Maybe it will help, to think of it like this:

If you (theoretically) split up the object in many, many (let's say infinitely many) pieces of equal mass, then gravity can pull equally in each of those pieces. They will all fall with equal acceleration $g$.

- If you put those pieces together to be one object, then of course the total gravitational pull $F$ on this object is the sum of all those pulls.
- The total mass $m$ is the sum of all the small masses.
- But each piece of mass is still only pulled downwards with the acceleration $g$ - that is *not* summed up.

Maybe this helps.

Comment: It's like mass interacts with an unseen force at the molecular level.  The unseen force that generates this energy is called gravity.  What is the source of the energy then do you think?  Matter itself?  Would that mean that matter has an attraction energy field?

Comment: Yes, mass is indeed being pulled at the molecular level. And we call that force the *gravitational force* or the *weight*. And exactly as CuriousOne mentioned in a comment above, understanding the *reason* that the gravitational force exists (that means, understanding why mass *attracts* other mass) is not at all easy. This is still a major challenge of physics, and as far as I know, *noone* actually understands this yet fully. So it is understandable that you have this question, but I am afraid I cannot give you the reason for gravity's existence - I can only help you understand how it works.

Comment: `The unseen force that generates this energy is called gravity.` Oh oh, now you mention **energy** again. Which energy is it that you say has been generated? I didn't mention energy anywhere. Please remember that force is **not** energy. If you remove the word "energy" then your sentences are true. For example: "What is the source of the **force** then do you think? Matter itself?" *Yes it is!* "Would that mean that matter has an attraction **force** field?" *Yes, you can consider it a force field. It is usual to talk about this as the **gravitational field** around a planet for example*

Comment: I think how gravity works is pretty fundamental, I was more wondering how it functioned and at the molecular level makes sense to me.  The thing is that this force is technically creating energy when it interacts with mass.  That is a curious issue to address.  That means the "force" is either energy or energy is being created in the mass because when gravity acts on the mass, the mass gains weight; weight is the same things as force except weight is generally done in terms of gravity so that xxx lbs = xxx lbs 32.2 ft/s^2  This acceleration is energy input.

Comment: Gravity functions in the same way at the molecular level. It simply causes attraction between masses, at the molecular level AND at the macro-scale. You *can* say that the presence of a gravitational force causes *potential* energy in a system. That is true, yes. (But this has got nothing to do with acceleration)

Comment: Well I am not sure what to say.  Energy is transferred mechanically and F=ma we can do a lot of math.  Look, if you are in your car and you accelerate it, you are spending energy and it transfers into momentum or inertia if you prefer.  I know the difference, but I don't mind which you choose.  That concept that energy is really the thing getting passed around into changing formats is why I use the word energy.

Comment: What are you asking in this comment?

Comment: Potential energy is the result of acceleration, but resisted by an equal and opposite (or stronger) force.

Comment: Potential energy is in $joules$. Acceleration is in $m/s^2$. This alone should tell that energy and acceleration are *not* the same. You can easily have energy without acceleration (as in a car moving with constant speed)

Comment: The names of the units tell you that energy isn't being transferred in them?  If energy is transferred, it is expressed in the equation in some say.  If it is on one side of the equation, it is on the other side too.  You are trying to say that the jump in units between the way energy is referred to in mechanical physics and the way it is referred to in electrical physics, that there is no coloration.  That is not correct.  Can't you convert H.P into Joules or Newtons?

Comment: What I said is that you can't rewrite $Joules$ into $m/s^2$. Regardless of the area of physics. Acceleration is just **not** the same as energy. Also, acceleration does **not** imply that energy is *transferred* in some way. Just think of a satellite in circular orbit around a planet. There is radial acceleration, but the energy content is constant; no energy is transferred. Who told you, that energy and acceleration must be related? This is simply not the case

Comment: This is wiki talking, but it's brief, "The joule (/ˈdʒuːl/), symbol J, is a derived unit of energy in the International System of Units.[1] It is equal to the energy transferred (or work done) to an object when a force of one newton acts on that object in the direction of its motion through a distance of one metre (1 newton metre or N·m)."  Joules and Newtons are related.  Guess what else is related to a Newton?  Acceleration!  A newton is based on 1kg = 1kg*m/s^2.  See that m/s^2?  That is acceleration :)

Comment: if you don't think energy is causing the acceleration, what do you think is?

Comment: @dw, force fields don't _generate_ energy, they _store_ it.  Imagine yourself lifting a heavy stone up to the top of a building.  You are doing _work_ on the stone (i.e., exerting energy).  We know that energy is _conserved_, so where did it go?  It is stored in the gravitational attraction between the Earth and the stone.  When energy is stored in a field like that, we call it _potential energy_.  If you drop the stone off the roof, you get the stored energy back as _kinetic energy_ (at least, up until the point where the stone smacks into the sidewalk.)

Comment: @jameslarge I didn't say force field, thought you are right about them, I said energy field, different.

Comment: Yes, work $W=\int \vec F\cdot d\vec x$ is *force times displacement*. But what if there is no displacement? I mean the whole point of this wiki quote is that work depends on **both** things! Not just force, but *both* force and displacement in the same direction. But you can have force without displacement and you can also have displacement without force, in which cases no work is done and no energy is transferred. The point is that energy doesn't follow force alone - you cannot conclude energy transfer just from force alone.

Comment: @Steeven I did not say energy is force alone, in fact during the transformation of mechanical to electrical energy, energy does not convert straight to force, but all force is energy, that remains a fact.  "you can also have displacement without force, in which cases no work is done and no energy is transferred"-Steeven How can you have displacement without force?  Force without displacement means the force is countered by an equal and opposite force.

Comment: `all force is energy, that remains a fact` But this is untrue - this is *not* a fact. Again, the units are completely different - and while a force is a vector, energy is a quantity. They are two different *types* of proporties. There are several differences. Force is not equal to energy! There is no more to it - but force can of course be included in a *formula* to calculate energy of some sort. `How can you have displacement without force?` Think of a spaceship drifting in space. It moves (at constant speed) but no forces are exerted on it.

Comment: @steeven P = F *V= W/t = 1 kg⋅m2/s2 =  F = ma = m * (v^2/r) = E

Comment: @steeven Do you know how these link?  Above may be wrong at this junction.                         P=FV=W/t                                           W=1kg⋅m2/s2 =F=ma=m*(v^2/r)=E

Comment: What is it they found link? In any case, did you consider the example I gave where there is motion but no force involved?

Comment: @dw
**About your equations**. This is true:

$$P=Fv=W/t$$

...but it is not equal to $F$. This is true (the last equal sign just for circular motion):

$$F=ma=m v^2/r$$

...but it is not equal to energy $E$.
**About the units**:

Force is in Newton's $[N]$ which can be rewritten as:

$$[N]=[kg\cdot m/s^2]$$

Energy is in Joules $[J]$, which can be rewritten as:

$$[J]=[N\cdot m]=[kg\cdot m^2/s^2]$$

Power $P$ is in Watts $[W]$, which can be rewritten as:

$$[W]=[J/ s]=[kg\cdot m^2/s^3]$$

Does this help clearing out the relationships?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30926/discussion-on-answer-by-steeven-gravitational-force).

Answer (score 1):

I think you are wondering why heavy and light things accelerate at the same rate when in free-fall (let's ignore air resistance for simplicity).

You probably notice that the *force* on the heavy object is greater than the force on the light object. This is correct.

You then wonder why the heavy object does not accelerate more, since the force is greater.

The answer is *inertia*. The heavy object feels a greater force, but it is harder to accelerate because it has more mass. The two effects exactly cancel out (inertial mass == gravitational mass) and so acceleration in a gravitational field is independent of mass.

One way to think about it is to imagine the object splitting up as it falls. Would you really expect the pieces to accelerate less as they separated? *[remember, we're doing this in a vaccum]*.

Comment: "You then wonder why the heavy object does not accelerate more, since the force is greater."  No, I wonder why the object with greater mass does not accelerate slower.  Why do large masses get more force put on them by gravity?

Comment: Inertia is not the answer, inertia is what is being ignored by gravity.  All masses accelerate at the same rate.  That is an infinitely different amount of forces generated by gravity instantaneously. I want to know why inertia is ignored.  Seems like a field to me.

Comment: @dw _Why do large masses get more force put on them by gravity?_ Imagine a 1lb brick - it gets a force $F$. Now bring up another 1lb brick - it also gets a force $F$. Now glue the two bricks together to make a 2lb brick. What is now the force? (_Answer: $2F$_).

Comment: I under stand if you double the mass, you get double the weight.  I was wondering why when you get double the mass, why you get the same acceleration with double the force.  Force and acceleration force are the same and not the same since they are on opposite sides of the equation.  They represent the same idea, accept force is a product of mass and acceleration.  The question was answered, gravity acts on molecules, not mass.  That is why weight is a good indicator of mass.

Comment: I want to correct the last sentence of the last statement saying, "gravity acts on molecules, not mass" by saying, "gravity acts on individual molecules of a mass."

Answer (score 0):

Gravity does not ignore the mass because the mass of the balls actually provides some of the gravitational pull. Their masses are do small however that they have little effect on the force of gravity. Mass is the fundamental property that governs the strength of interaction between the earth and the balls.

Comment: The difference in force generated by gravity in a 1 lbs ball vs the force generated by gravity in a 100,000 ton ball is due to the increased gravity from the ball?  Any math to go with that?

Comment: $F = {Gm_1m_2 \over r^2}$... There you go.

Comment: Let me be more clear.  There is math that shows why earth has gravity and it is based on mass.  The question is, since the difference between a 1 pound brick and a 2 pound brick is not going to create a difference in the acceleration due to mass, but the force is measurably different.  That is what you have to figure out to answer this question.

Comment: @dw: The force on a 2lb brick is _twice_ the force on a 1lb brick. But... the 2lb brick is _twice_ as hard to move (i.e., it has twice as much inertia). Hence the _acceleration_ is the same. I think you are mixing up the chain of events: Presence of mass in a gravitational field -> Force -> Acceleration.

Comment: @OwenBoyle  Twice the mass means twice as much energy to accelerate.  Why is gravity putting out twice as much energy to force the mass down as the mass right next to it?  Why doesn't the smaller mass accelerate faster since it requires less energy to move?

Comment: @dw I just read your comments on the thread above (with Steeven). You have a fundamental misunderstanding of the definitions of energy, force, acceleration and other properties. This makes it hard to explain things to you since you misunderstand the vocabulary used. I'll try one last time: _Why doesn't the smaller mass accelerate faster since it requires less energy to move?_ Because the force is smaller; energy has nothing to do with the calculation. Potential energy is converting into kinetic energy, but you don't need to consider energy at all to understand what it is going on.

Comment: @OwenBoyle If energy is expressed as Acceleration=A: and F=force, W=work, P=power: and m=mass, s=distance, t=time: energy translates in this manner.  A*m=F   F*s=W  W/t=P  That means acceleration just has mass, then distance, then time stacked with it, but it never goes away.